# How to send somebody a link to a movie or TV show on Netflix?

Tags: netflix

I couldn't find a way to get a URL. If I am watching a movie, the URL has a lot of tracker info and perhaps session ID, so I don't want to send that. I could only tell the person to "search" by some title... it can work but it totally defeats the functionality of Web and URL.

I found a way, which is to use a link to the actor or actress or director:
https://www.netflix.com/browse/person/39020

but is there a way to get a simple URL to a movie or TV show or episode?

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem very complicated from the Netflix website. Share it as you would share any other link:

1. Start watching the show / movie that you want to share.
2. Copy the URL and that's the share link.

The URL is something like:

```
https://www.netflix.com/watch/80989928?trackId=12345678&tctx=blahblahblah
```

But you can delete the query portion and just share this part:

```
https://www.netflix.com/watch/80989928
```

Answer (score 0):

From Netflix help center

> #### How can I share movies and TV shows with someone?
>
> Netflix offers a way to share your favorite movies and TV shows with your friends and family. This sharing is optional and uses the standard sharing tool that comes on most mobile and tablet devices, including:
>
> - Apple iPad, iPhone, and iPod touch
> - Android phones and tablets

As the help article doesn't mention the web, it looks that sharing from the web is not supported but might be possible. I suggest you to search for web-browser extension that adds this feature to the Netflix web app.

Answer (score 0):

Netflix obviously changed it:

Now we can share the URL like this:

1. Search and find that movie or TV show
2. Hover the mouse over the desired thumbnail
3. Click the "Down Arrow" round icon so that it show as a preview dialog in the window
4. The URL of the webpage will silently change to https://www.netflix.com/search?q=squid%20game&jbv=81040344 (this is for the TV series Squid Game)
5. Just copy and paste this URL on the address bar in your browser and send to other people

This is not a traditional way... usually I don't expect a pop up modal or dialog to change the URL of the webpage.  But this is the way it is now and it is working.

But note that in this case, the query string is also in the URL, and it may be some privacy concern, because if you searched for Squid Game and then get to Seinfeld using the Down Arrow icon, then your URL looks like this:

https://www.netflix.com/search?q=squid%20game&jbv=70153373

and there are two methods to change it:

1. paste that URL above back to the browser and press Enter. Now the URL changes to https://www.netflix.com/title/70153373 which only has the ID to the movie or show.
2. Use the long URL above and make it into https://www.netflix.com/title/70153373 yourself. You need to do some editing.